# Lambda function to direct Lex to new intent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm trying to use a lambda function to send lex to a new intent based on the value of an incoming slot:

Like this

```
 public override LexResponse Process(LexEvent lexEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var slots = lexEvent.CurrentIntent.Slots;
        var sessionAttributes = lexEvent.SessionAttributes ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
        DesiredVehicleYesNo type;
        if (slots.ContainsKey("DesiredVehicleYesNo"))
        {
            Enum.TryParse(slots["DesiredVehicleYesNo"], out type);
        }
        else
        {
            type = DesiredVehicleYesNo.Null;
        }

        switch (type)
        {
            case DesiredVehicleYesNo.YES:
                Dictionary<string, string> s = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                s.Add("DesiredVehicle", null);
                //return ConfirmIntent(sessionAttributes, "DesiredVehicleYes", s, new LexResponse.LexMessage() { Content = "That's great! Let's get started.", ContentType = MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE });
                //return ElicitSlot(sessionAttributes,"DesiredVehicleYes",null,"DesiredVehicle", new LexResponse.LexMessage() { Content = "That's great! Let's get started.", ContentType = MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE });

            case DesiredVehicleYesNo.NO:
                return ConfirmIntent(sessionAttributes, "DesiredVehicleNo", new Dictionary<string,string>(), new LexResponse.LexMessage() { Content = "Well, that's ok, I can help you choose", ContentType = MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE });

        }
```

I'm just not sure what return type I should be using for this? ConfirmIntent, ElicitSlot, ElicitIntent? Also I do need to be passing slots back, I want the new intent to use it's own prompts to fill the slots related to that intent.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ConfirmIntent` and supply the `intentName` and `slots` of the intent you want to switch to.

[Lex Response Format Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format)

> ConfirmIntent — Informs Amazon Lex that the user is expected to give a yes or no answer to confirm or deny the current intent.
>   You must include the intentName and slots fields. The slots field must contain an entry for each of the slots configured for the specified intent. If the value of a slot is unknown, you must set it to null. You must include the message field if the intent's confirmationPrompt field is null. If you specify both the message field and the confirmationPrompt field, the response includes the contents of the confirmationPrompt field. The responseCard field is optional.

So you can supply your own message, but make sure it is written as a Yes/No question. Because `ConfirmIntent` will expect a Yes/No response from the user.

This approach will always trigger the intent that you supplied in `intentName`. So you will have to handle the user's response there.
If the user says "yes" then the `confirmationStatus` will hold the value `Confirmed`.
If the user says "no" then the `confirmationStatus` will hold the value `Denied`.

Make sure that the slots you pass back are correct for that new intent. You can pass them pre-filled to use what the user already gave you; or set to `null` to allow the new intent to ask the user to fill those slots again.

Comment: in my case though, even if the user's were saying completely unrelated words from yes/no, it was taking it as yes/no. eg: **bot:** do you want to continue, **user:** mobile, **bot:** thanks for confirming

Comment: @sid8491 (though I'm not sure why someone should say anything like "mobile" to a well written yes/no prompt) I'm glad you added a workaround, it would be better to not need a confirmation prompt so we can smoothly transition to a different intent.

Comment: tell that to the people in testing department :P they made my life hell while testing the bot. i have put one more check on `inputTranscript` that it does not hold any garbage value, if it does prompt again **answer in yes/no you dumb**

Comment: btw i wasn't questioning your answer, it is perfect (already upvoted it :P ), i was just mentioning a problem i faced in that method.

Comment: hahaha that is so true. Some people try to throw off the chatbot in the most unrealistic ways. I've added input fail catches that return something like **"Come on, you can't expect me to handle that, try again."** lol and people like it! They think, "Oh! The chatbot just told me off!" hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConfirmIntent` as Jay suggested, however if you do not want to prompt anything to user there is a hacky way to achieve this:

- give access to invoke lambda functions to your calling lambda
  function i.e lambda function of intent-A
- get the name of backend lambda function of intent-B
- call that lambda function with all the inputs using boto3
- response will be in 'Payload' key of response object
- get the response using read() method
- get actual output in ['dialogAction']['message']['content']
- return using default close() method

Here is sample code for same:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')
data = {'messageVersion': '1.0', 'invocationSource': 'FulfillmentCodeHook', 'userId': '###', 
        'sessionAttributes': {}, 'requestAttributes': None, 
        'bot': {'name': '###', 'alias': '$LATEST', 'version': '$LATEST'}, 
        'outputDialogMode': 'Text', 
        'currentIntent': {'name': '###', 'slots': {'###': '###'}, 
        'slotDetails': {'###': {'resolutions': [], 'originalValue': '###'}}, 
        'confirmationStatus': 'None'}, 
        'inputTranscript': '###'}
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='{intent-B lambda function}',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps(data)
)
output = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())['dialogAction']['message']['content']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Boto derives its name from the Portuguese name given to types of dolphins native to the Amazon River."  Of course.  Now you know.

Comment: @DragonLord lol thank you for this amazing piece of trivia.